# ¿Cómo verificara un campo único sin distinción entre mayúscula/minúscula?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

Dados los siguientes archivos

`models.py`

```
    class Cargo(Base):
        nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre del Cargo',
                                  max_length=100, unique=True)
        descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name='Descripción')
```

`forms.py`

```
    def clean_nombre(self):
        nombre = self.cleaned_data.get('nombre')
        # Recupera los registros sin distinción entre mayúscula/minúscula
        if Elector.objects.filter(nombre__iexact=nombre):
            raise ValidationError('YA EXISTE UN CARGO REGISTRADO CON ESE NOMBRE')
        else:
        # Ese nombre no ha sido registrado aun
            return nombre
```

Esto funciona para evitar que se cree una instancia del modelo `Cargo`, con el mismo nombre, sin distinguir entre mayúsculas o minúscula, ej. si existe un registro de un cargo con el nombre *"Auditor"*, no se permitiría otro registro con el nombre *"AUDITOR"*, *"auditor"*,*"auditoR"*, etc.

**EL PROBLEMA**

Cuando cuando se ingresa a la vista para actualizar, si no hay ninguna modificación en la entrada del formulario correspondiente al campo `nombre`, no permite actualizar el registro. En este caso, si intento actualizar el campo `descripcion`, al momento de enviar la petición `POST` daría error porque encuentra al mismo registro que se intenta actualizar con el mismo valor del campo `nombre`, que lógicamente esta en el formulario

Las respectivas vistas correspondientes al archivo `views.py`:

**Crear un nuevo cargo**

```
    class CargoCreateView(CreateView):
        model = Cargo
        form_class = CargoForm
        template_name = 'create.html'

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
            self.object = None
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context
```

**Actualizar un nuevo cargo**

```
    class CargoUpdateView(UpdateView):
        model = Cargo
        form_class = CargoForm
        template_name = 'create.html'

        def get_success_url(self):
            return self.object.get_absolute_url()

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context
```

**Título Gracias**

Answer (score 1):

Comprendiendo el código aportado, el error apreciable es que estás haciendo un mal uso de los métodos clean_, o directamente requieres dos formularios distintos, una para **carga** y otro para **actualizar**.

Te indico esto porque el método clean_nombre se lleva a cabo tanto en la **carga** como en la **actualización**. Y en el caso de la actualización, en tu caso esto será erroneo.

Lo que más te sugeriría en este caso, es el generar otro formulario más, explícito para la actualización y con la comprobación de si existe un registro con ese cargo previamente cargado. Y que tenga el siguiente método:

```
def clean_nombre(self):
    nombre = self.cleaned_data.get('nombre')
    # Recupera los registros sin distinción entre mayúscula/minúscula
    if Elector.objects.filter(nombre__iexact=nombre):
        return nombre
    else:
        #En caso de que se quiera actualizar un Cargo que no exista
        raise ValidationError('NO EXISTE UN CARGO REGISTRADO CON ESE NOMBRE')
```